# Desperate image positioning problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is this: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?11b1fcb689.png

---

Edit: Added a fuller picture of what I'm trying to do. I can make it look right using absolute positioning, but when the window size is too small, the content slides off the page without a horizontal scrollbar. That's why I want to use relative positioning for the divs. Thanks again. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?75c33eaf6e.png

---

I only know how to do this using absolutely positioned divs, but content in absolute divs will slide off the page when the window is too small. Essentially, the image is vertically centered and aligned right on the left half of the screen. If the window is too small, I'd rather have a horizontal scrollbar than losing part of the image.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Mike

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.footer {
  color: #202054;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
a { border: 0px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
span { text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
a.footer:hover {
  color: #EE001E;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<img style="position: absolute; right: 50%; top: 50%; margin-top: -128px;" src="Resources/chart.png" width="432" height="256"/>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-top: -200px; width: 368px; height: 400px;">
  <!-- text content -->
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 20px; bottom: 20px;">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.company.com" >
    <img class="footer" src="Resources/logo.png" alt="company" width="21" height="13"/>
  </a>
  <a class="footer" href="#">Terms of Use</a>
  <a class="footer" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
  <span class="footer" style="color: #7E7E7E;">Copyright &#169; 2009 Company Inc. All rights reserved.</span>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't really need to be absolute positioning, but please show also the other content and the gridlines if possible.

Comment: This questions seems to be a continuation of his previous question (found here: tinyurl.com/swarts1 , TinyUrl'd because of link formatting), it may help to know of the history of the question.

Comment: Yes it is a continuation of my old question. I've added the code so it won't be necessary to look at the old post. Also, there's a more explicit layout image that I linked to. With this information, do you know if this layout is possible?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem using a full-screen div container and an overflow, but it didn't work. Here's that code:

<style>
.chart {
width: 432px;
height: 256px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -128px 0 0 -432px;
overflow: auto;
display: block;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;"
  <img class="chart" src="Resources/chart.png" width="432" height="256"/>
</div>

If anyone has any ideas, please share. I'm at a loss.
Mike

Comment: I'll be updating my answer below shortly. Thanks for updating the information.

Comment: I answered your most recent question below in my answer, sorry I never saw it until now. Must have missed the notification. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can work with either `absolute` or `relative` positioning as long as the image width and height are defined.

## Update for your recent edit

The issue is that you need to use relative positioning. You should also have a container DIV for the image and the sidebar div, because they will still act incorrectly with only the body as a parent.

You then need a min-width on the container div, set to the min-width which you illustrate in the newer image.  These things together will give you what you want.

Note that the sidebar content needs a different margin in this code I'll be posting. I'm not sure why because I'm a little rusty with my CSS but now that both are `relative` positioned, if you have no negative margin on the sidebar content, the top of it will be aligned to the bottom of the image. I know that `margin-top: -256px` will get it aligned with the top of the image. Then to vertically center them you need to *add half of their difference* or `(256 - 400) / 2`, so you add `-72px` to the `-256px` margin to center them again.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background: #DDD;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
}

img#image {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -128px 0 0 -432px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}

div#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -328px 0 0 0;
  width: 368px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
}

.footer {
  color: #202054;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a { border: 0px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

span { text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

a.footer:hover {
  color: #EE001E;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <img id="image" src="" width="432" height="256"/>

    <div id="sidebar" style="">
      <!-- text content -->
      content
    </div>

</div>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 20px; bottom: 20px;">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.company.com" >
    <img class="footer" src="" alt="company" width="21" height="13" />
  </a>
  <a class="footer" href="#">Terms of Use</a>
  <a class="footer" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
  <span class="footer" style="color: #7E7E7E;">Copyright &#169; 2009 Company Inc. All rights reserved.</span>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Note I added colors to help me along, and also I found that you must add `display: block` to the image.

Hope this helps.

Note: The `min-width` value was arbitrary. It just needs to be greater than the width of both elements. You may want to play around and see what width the sidebar starts to fall off the page (clipping to the right is unavoidable in browsers)

Comment: Updated. Hopefully you can help!

Comment: OK, updated. The image no longer falls off the left of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't able to get it to work. It was alright, except it wasn't vertically centered. The top half of both the image and text divs were cut off. The "top: 50%" did not work. I am testing in Safari 4. Any thoughts?

Comment: It centers vertically for me in Safari 4, and every other browser I test.  Did you paste in my exact code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
<div style="width:50%; height:100%; position:absolute; text-align:right; overflow:auto">
<img src='...'>
</div>
```

But to center image vertical you will need to put it into table or use JavaScript.

Comment: Not true. You can use css to center vertically. Just not straightforward.

Comment: Also as I said in my answer, you can center vertically if you have the height/width of the element, which he does. I'm not sure if this is what cdm9002 is alluding to, or if he's talking about things like `table-cell` display properties, etc. :)